# Stateful Session Bean not passivated after Cache Idle Timeout(cache-idle-timeout-in-seconds) elapsed

Tags: ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1, stateful-session-bean

I am trying to understand Stateful Session bean life cycle.I am particularly interested when activation and passivation life cycle callback invoked.I created a demo to understand this scenario. Here is My code :

My Remote interface is :

```
package com.orbit.stateful;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import java.util.List;
@Remote
public interface ShoppingCart 
{
    public void addItem(String itemName);
    public void removeItem(String item);
    public List<String> getAllItems();
    public void finishShopping();
}
```

My Stateful session bean class is as follow:

```
package com.orbit.stateful;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.Remove;
import javax.ejb.PrePassivate;
import javax.ejb.PostActivate;
import javax.ejb.StatefulTimeout;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
//import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
@Stateful
//@StatefulTimeout(value=5L,unit=TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public class ShoppingCartBean implements ShoppingCart 
{
    private List<String> itemList;
    public ShoppingCartBean(){
        System.out.println("Stateful SessionBean Constructor Called");
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void intialize(){
        System.out.println("Initializing shopping Cart");
        itemList=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public void addItem(String itemName){
        itemList.add(itemName);
    }
    public void removeItem(String item){
        itemList.remove(item);
    }
    public List<String> getAllItems(){
        return itemList;
    }
    @Remove
    public void finishShopping(){
        System.out.println("I am finished with Shopping");
    }
    @PreDestroy
    public void tidyUp(){
        System.out.println("Remove Shopping Bean");
    }
    @PrePassivate
    public void logPassivation(){
        System.out.println("Passivating Now");
    }
    @PostActivate
    public void logActivation(){
        System.out.println("Activating Now");
    }
}
```

And standalone client for this bean is :

```
package com.orbit.stateful;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.List;
public class ShoppingCartClient  
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                    "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
         props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                    "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
         props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
                    "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
          props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
          props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
          Context ctx=new InitialContext(props);
          ShoppingCart sc=(ShoppingCart)ctx.lookup("com.orbit.stateful.ShoppingCart");
          sc.addItem("J2SE");
          //Thread.sleep(17000);
          sc.addItem("J2EE");
          sc.addItem("JDBC");
          List<String> books=sc.getAllItems();
          for (String str: books )
          {
              System.out.println("Books is : "+ str);
          }
          //sc.finishShopping();

    }
}
```

Now I have set `Cache Idle Timeout`=20 in GlassFish 3.1.2
But still My stateful session bean is not passivating after 20 seconds. am I doing something wrong or something is not happening correctly in Glashfish ?Help me to understand this.
Thanks in Advance